# TinyMCE weird image alignment using floating and margin: auto

Tags: html, image, tinymce, alignment, tinymce-4

I'm using TinyMCE 4. The behaviour when aligning images within the editor is odd.

- Align Left

  - Actual: `style="float: left;"`
  - Expected: `<p style="text-align: left"><img ... /></p>`
- Align Right

  - Actual: `style="float: right;"`
  - Expected: `<p style="text-align: right"><img ... /></p>`
- Align Center

  - Actual: `style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto"`
  - Expected: `<p style="text-align: center"><img ... /></p>`

Applying floating causes unexpected behaviour. For instance, take two images on two lines like so:

```
[img 1]
[img 2]
```

If I apply left alignment to the first, and right alignment to the second, they come out on the same line due to the floating:

```
[img 1]                        [img 2]
```

I expect it to behave the same as text:

```
[img 1]
                               [img 2]
```

Is there a way to change or override this behaviour in TinyMCE 4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, TinyMCE offers an [onNodeChange](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3:event.tinymce.Editor.onNodeChange) event. Here, you can detect what type of node was altered and how. Here I was able to detect the source node was an image and the attributes that had been added. I could then apply the expected markup in its place.

Answer (score 0):

Since your floated elements are losing it's height, they are lining in one line.

All you need is additional element between them with `clear:both;` in css. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aqr7jy5o/2/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I think you missed my point. I don't want it to float, I want it to align.

Comment: @flem So use `text-align: left/right` and `display: inline(-block);`

Comment: This question is in regards to TinyMCE. I don't write the markup, the editor does. I need to alter the behaviour of the alignment feature in the editor. I can't ask my end users to update the source.